# My php don't works with the element td, but without it works well

Tags: php, oracle10g, oracle-call-interface

i have problems on "**echos with td elements**", only on the first select of the form, because the other code that i have works well only if the first select works....

So, that's my code:

```
$stallFirstSel=oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM ACTIVIDAD');
oci_execute($stallFirstSel);
echo "<table><tr>";
echo "<td><form id='formActis' method='POST' action='reserves_es.php'>";
echo "<select name='selActi[]'>";
while (($row=oci_fetch_array($stallFirstSel,OCI_BOTH))!=false){
      echo "<option id='optActi'>".$row['NOM']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo "<td><input type='submit' value='Enviar'></td>";
echo "</form></td></tr>";
```

And if i modify it deleting all the td tags, it works well and all the other code works too because i have the condition `if(isset($_POST['selActi']))`:

```
$stallFirstSel=oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM ACTIVIDAD');
oci_execute($stallFirstSel);
echo "<table><tr>";
echo "<form id='formActis' method='POST' action='reserves_es.php'>";
echo "<select name='selActi[]'>";
while (($row=oci_fetch_array($stallFirstSel,OCI_BOTH))!=false){
      echo "<option id='optActi'>".$row['NOM']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Enviar'>";
echo "</form></tr>";
```

That's all, if anyone can help me or know how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use this code

Example 1

```
$stallFirstSel=oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM ACTIVIDAD');
oci_execute($stallFirstSel);
echo "<form id='formActis' method='POST' action='reserves_es.php'><table><tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<select name='selActi[]'>";
while (($row=oci_fetch_array($stallFirstSel,OCI_BOTH))!=false){
      echo "<option id='optActi'>".$row['NOM']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo "</td><td><input type='submit' value='Enviar'></td>";
echo " </tr></table></form>";
```

Example 2

```
$stallFirstSel=oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM ACTIVIDAD');
oci_execute($stallFirstSel);
echo "<table><tr>";
echo "<td><form id='formActis' method='POST' action='reserves_es.php'>";
echo "<select name='selActi[]'>";
while (($row=oci_fetch_array($stallFirstSel,OCI_BOTH))!=false){
      echo "<option id='optActi'>".$row['NOM']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo " &nbsp; <input type='submit' value='Enviar'></form></td>";
echo " </tr></table>";
```

Comment: then you can use the second example ( EXample 2) so in that you can remove the </table> tag and place it where ever you want

Comment: oh! I don't see it, i don't see that if the condition "if(isset($_POST['selActi']))" doesn't match, the code put in there doesn't works, because i close the table on the third "isset", my fault, i'm going to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You missed a  (closing tag) after the while { } 
     echo "";

Comment: not, i'm looking the code that is fixed now, but i don't see what u answered, mhm...

Answer (score 0):

You are using `<td>` tag recursively without statring new `<table>`.

Here is your clear code.

```
$stallFirstSel=oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM ACTIVIDAD');
oci_execute($stallFirstSel);
echo "<form id='formActis' method='POST' action='reserves_es.php'>";
echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo "<select name='selActi[]'>";
            while (($row=oci_fetch_array($stallFirstSel,OCI_BOTH))!=false){
                  echo "<option id='optActi'>".$row['NOM']."</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo "<input type='submit' value='Enviar'>";
        echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: you can use `<form>` inside `<table>` also. don't forget to close tags as they are started in nested structure.